Unable to connect to SQL Server using ODBC through PHP
I am trying to replicate a cloud web-server to on-prem. The cloud version works fine, but having followed the same steps to create the server I'm running into an issue with it's ability to connect to a remote database.
I have an Apache web-server running on Ubuntu with PHP & ODBC Installed.
The database server's firewall is configured to allow connections over 1433 from the web-server's IP address. The credentials are correct.
I am receiving the following error:
Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection, SQL state 08001 in SQLConnect in /var/www/cb-db-conn/index.phpon line17
Occasionally, a different error is received:
Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [OpenSSL library could not be loaded, make sure OpenSSL 1.0 or 1.1 is installed], SQL state 08001 in SQLConnect in var/www/cb-db-conn/index.phpon line17
Line 17 for reference:
$conn = odbc_connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=$serverName,1433;Database=$dbName;Uid={$connectionOptions['Uid']};PWD={$connectionOptions['PWD']}", '', '');
I have confirmed:

Both OpenSSL and ODBC are installed.
The credentials are correct.
Port 1433 on the database server is open to the web-server.
SQL Server is listening on port 1433.
Pinging the database from the web-server is successful
The cloud web server does not have any issue connecting


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/resolve-connectivity-errors-overview

@MitchWheat. Thank you. There's no issue with the database itself. I am able to connect through the cloud web-server and from my local machine without any problems. The issue is somewhere in the on-prem web server.

@MitchWheat I'm sorry I'm not sure what you mean?

@MitchWheat I'm providing the login credentials for the server though including the UID? The same PHP code runs fine on the cloud web-server.

"[OpenSSL library could not be loaded, make sure OpenSSL 1.0 or 1.1 is installed]"
You've not installed the ODBC driver and its dependencies properly.

This should be the correct answer, but it isn't. See below:
msodbcsql17 is already the newest version (17.8.1.1-1)
openssl is already the newest version (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.16).
